Ruamel preserving backslashes to indicate a line break
Does ruamel have an option to preserve backslash line breaks? Consider the following example.

the text was exported using SnakeYaml and included carriage returns.
the wrapping and text length was such that the \r\n was split as part of the wrapping

❯ cat example.yaml 
---
items:
- description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmode\
    \ ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\r\n\r\nUt enim ad minim veniam, quis nost. \r\
    \n \r\n\r\nDuis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dol\
    \ nulla pariatur.\r\n\r\nExcepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt ."

Using the following script to read and write the same file
❯ cat parser_yaml.py                              
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

# Create a YAML instance
yaml = YAML()

# Read the YAML file
with open('example.yaml', 'r') as file:
    data = yaml.load(file)

# Here you can modify `data` if needed, for example:
# data['new_key'] = 'new_value'

# Write the modified data back to the YAML file
with open('example_modified.yaml', 'w') as file:
    yaml.dump(data, file)

print("YAML file read and written successfully.")

Upon rewriting, the \ line endings are lost, meaning the \r\n is now split by a new line.
❯ python ./parser_yaml.py                         
YAML file read and written successfully.

❯ diff example_modified.yaml example.yaml         
0a1
> ---
2,6c3,6
< - description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmode
<     ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\r\n\r\nUt enim ad minim veniam, quis nost. \r
<     \n \r\n\r\nDuis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
<     dol nulla pariatur.\r\n\r\nExcepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt
<     ."
---
> - description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmode\
>     \ ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\r\n\r\nUt enim ad minim veniam, quis nost. \r\
>     \n \r\n\r\nDuis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dol\
>     \ nulla pariatur.\r\n\r\nExcepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt ."

It can no longer be parsed correctly, e.g.
❯ yq '.items[0].description' example.yaml         
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmode ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nost. 
 

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dol nulla pariatur.

Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt .

vs
❯ yq '.items[0].description' example_modified.yaml
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmode ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

 t enim ad minim veniam, quis nost. 
 

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dol nulla pariatur.

Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt .


ruamel.yaml only preserves newlines in literal and folded block style scalars, not in quoted scalars, which are just loaded as strings, and those have no information about whether and where to put extra backslashes.
The same hold for the DoubleQuotedScalar instance that it would be loaded into if you had specified yaml.preserve_quotes = True.
ruamel.yaml inherited its mechanism to collapse various newline endings from PyYAML, and that seems to me what gets rid of the carriage returns.
If you could dump from within snakeyaml, in such a way that the quoted scalars would instead be literal style, including the backslashes, then these should not be interpreted on loading.
